# Lightning component with placeholder

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to create a lightning component to be used on the lightning page. In the component I want to have a placeholder for other components, so the user can add other components per via drag and drop in the lightning app builder. Is it possible?

PS: There is a standard component "tabs" that have exactly that what I want. Can I do it on the custom lightning component?

[image]

Comment: For we cannot do so. You can create a attribute with type as "Aura.component[]" and then add that attribute in design of component you will see a error "Failed to save TestComp.design: The flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes interface doesn't support these attribute types in the design resource: component[]."

Comment: @ManjotSingh Yes, that attribute can be used only in the lightning TEMPLATE components. I want to develop a normal lightning component for the lightning page.

Comment: for what its worth, i know this Idea has been listed for a while [Drag communities components into other components in Community Builder](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dx5HAAS)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot at the moment (or at least there is no documented way of doing so), the only components that support drag and drop placeholder/regions are the following:

1. [custom theme layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)
2. [custom templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm)

the following Ideas are still pending approval for making this feature available:

- [Drag communities components into other components in Community Builder](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dx5HAAS)
- [Drag and drop regions on Custom lightning components](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lLJlQAM)

and as far as the aura frameworks components go, it looks like this may be made available some time in the future since there are several drag and drop reference components under development which can be seen on the [forcedotcom GitHub Repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui). Unfortuantely, I cant provide any insight on how far up in the list of priorities this is.