# How to create custom Tabset & Tabs for use on Lightning App Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, tab

When I create a **Lightning App Page**

[image]

the standard Tabs component is not available for use:

[image]

I would like to create a custom Tabs component that will let me drop other component into it?

I know how to create the tabs:

```
<lightning:tabset variant="default">
    <lightning:tab id="item-1">
    <aura:set attribute="label">
        Tab 1
    </aura:set>
        Other component can be drag and dropped here?
    </lightning:tab>
    <lightning:tab id="item-2">
    <aura:set attribute="label">
        Tab 2
    </aura:set>
        Other component can be drag and dropped here?
    </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```

How do I extend it to be able to drag and drop other components into each tab, in the same why the standard tabs component works?

Comment: If you are creating record pages, the **tab** will be available. You can call your custom component inside the tab within your component markup if you want it to be static.

Comment: Are you asking about being able to drag other components into your component in the Lightning App Builder?

Comment: @sanketkumar as stated `When I create a Lightning App Page` therefore I am not creating a `Record Page`

Comment: @KeithC yes, that is what I am asking :)

Comment: FYI, this [Lightning component with placeholder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213065/lightning-component-with-placeholder) says no.